# Referencing Table Entries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I'm working on a project in rails where I have a database of products, and I'm looking to use forms to manipulate them.

However, I'm having a great deal of difficulty figuring out how to do this.

I tried to use the standard:

```
<%= form_for(@product) %>
...
<% end %>
```

to send an entry to my product controller, but that returns a nil/empty field error.

My method to remove products from inventory is below.  I strongly suspect this to be highly incorrect, but I have yet to figure out how to get far enough to even receive an error with that:

```
def ship
    @products.where(@products.code = params[:code]).quantity -= 1 
end
```

If there is any way that anybody could guide me in the right direction, I would be highly grateful.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: You need to store the result of your query in an instance variable product before using the product instance var in your form_for helper and then you wont have that error however your query also looks incorrect.  Tell us what it is you're trying to do and we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, let me know what else do you need.

```
def ship
  @product = Product.find_by(code: params[:code]) # or you can use :code => params[:code], but not an equal sign
  @product.quantity -= 1
  if @product.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {}
    end
  end
end
```

- `where` returns an array or objects.
- You after negating the quantity you should save it or update product on the go
- You should respond back or else you'll get `template missing` error, OR you can redirect to some page

Comment: This works up to the @product.quantity line.  Here, I'm getting an error that this is an undefined method for nil:NilClass.  Since quantity is one of the columns in my database table, should that create a method named #quantity, or is there another method that I should use to access that entry?

Comment: I also had to change the find_by to Product.find_by, so that it would not give me an undefined method error.

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing that out. Yes, you can access `quantity` just like that. You can get and set its value. Setting value is temporary in this case. You have to save your object, so it gets written to your database. Now what other problem do you face?

Comment: How do I write this change to my database? I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: `@product.save` will do that. You may verify by opening `rails console`. Fine out more about rails console [here](http://slash7.com/2006/12/21/secrets-of-the-rails-console-ninjas/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still not sure why my @product variable has a nil class, but I'm getting a much better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Where do you get your that `nil` error. Which line?

Comment: I'm getting it at the @product.quantity -= 1 line, it says that I can't use quantity because that method is not defined for nil class.

Comment: That is because it didn't fine any `product` with `code` that you provided in params. Or possibly `params[:code]` could be nil. I suggest you check your rails server log to verify if code is being passed in your params. Next open `rails console`, and and try `Product.find_by(code: 23)` (whatever is your product code), if that gives any output.

Comment: I am not able to enter a code into my form, it simply takes me to the ship method and gives me the nil error at this line.

Comment: Ah, then `code` in your params is nil. So basically your searching like this, `Product.find_by(code: nil)`, which is giving out nil in your `@product` variable.

Comment: Ah, okay, I get it. So, how can I render a view of the form so that people can enter information?

Comment: @Mascasc, I would love to answer that, but I think its getting out of the scope of this question's answer. It would be awesome if you could walk through the official rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). You'll get much more insight about the code you're dealing with right now. Thank You.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help.  I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck venturing into rails in depth. :)